# Valuation of company based on earnings only?

Tags: value-investing

I notice that a lot of valuation guidance, [such as some online calculators](https://www.calcxml.com/calculators/business-valuation), make company valuation a function of earnings. Therefore a company with small earnings (or no earnings) is valued at 0. For example, a company with $50 million in sales, but $1 million in earnings every year, might be valued at only $5 million, for example, which does not seem logical to me, especially for a growing company. Nobody would sell a growing company with $50 million in sales for $5 million.

What is the story here? Is there a another valuation method that is more reasonable? Does anybody actually use the bogus earnings-based valuation or is that just a pro forma method with no real practical application?

Comment: A company is only worth as much as *someone else* is willing to pay for it. Without knowing who that someone else is, and what they are thinking, then I'd go with the latter of your options.

Comment: Valuations in general are biased and based on many assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

The valuation method depends on what the company does and its upside potential.

For example, The figures you quote, $50M sales, $1M EBITDA, $5M price would be a standard transaction for, say, the sale of a Honda dealership in a small to mid-sized town.

On the other hand, Google purchased Youtube for $1.67B before it made a dollar of revenue. And Amazon had a market cap of several billion before it made its first dollar. So valuation is highly dependent upon the nature of the subject company involved.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to like this answer, but frankly if sales don't increase net earnings, then they don't add value.

Imagine 2 companies in the same market:

Company A has $100M in sales, and $10M in net earnings.

Company B has $50M in sales, and $10M in net earnings.

Which company *barring all other information* seems more stable, to you? Or more profitable? Assume a new market goes up, with total possible sales of this product of $50M. If the two companies continue earning net income in a similar proportion to sales (which may or may not be a good assumption, but it *is* partially one of the core assumptions used in earnings-based growth projections), then Company A will earn $1 for every new $10 in sales, whereas company B will earn $1 for every $5 in new sales.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise valuation is really more of an art than a science.  The general idea is you're buying the future profitability of the company.  "How much would you pay for a machine that prints $1,000,000 per year?"  The answer is probably significantly more than $1,000,000.  How much would you pay for the same machine but isn't actually done yet and might not ever work?

No one factor can be reliably used to value a company.  There is no single multiple that can be applied to top line sales to result in a valuation that would be reliable at all.

Additionally you'd have to consider any number of external issues like if there was a big pending lawsuit or there was legislation floating around seeking to restrict sales of the company's product or any number of other possible potentially detrimental scenarios.

Comment: I am talking about a company that has no "problems" like a large debt load. Obviously, you can downgrade a company by having it located in Zimbabwe, having $1 billion in debt, under indictment by the UN, and the headquarters is in flames. I am talking about a normal US tech company with no problems.

Comment: @TylerDurden "Tech company with no problems" well with a tech company, are you sure the tech is actually going to deliver what they promise? It is very naive to assume that a company not literally on fire is A-OK.

Comment: You mean like when AOL bought Time Warner? How about when Netscape and Yahoo! were big Internet names? There are more than a few tech companies that have gone away or at least have had their stock take a massive hit over the years.